# Is it possible to open tabs in selenium(python) using a link that is generated by python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a program which generates a link in python and names its N. It will generate multiple such links and I wanted to use selenium to open it in Google Chrome.

I tried this
`browser.execute_script('''window.open('N', "_blank");''')` for all my N links hoping it would open a bunch of tabs with the links but it just seems to open empty tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It is, you have to insert the url properly in that execute script:

```
def open_random_url(url):
    driver.execute_script('window.open("{}","_blank");'.format(url))
 
open_random_url('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: I probably couldn't convey my question probably so I'll rephrase.
Before I run my program, I am unaware of the link that will open up. My program generates a link, names it 'N' and attempts to open in a browser, in this format `browser.execute_script('''window.open('N', "_blank");''')`, which works perfectly if I manually enter a url in place of N. But since I can't manually input a url, I would like my program to open the url generated by the program.

Comment: browser.execute_script('window.open("{}","_blank");'.format(N)) if the N is returned as a valid url string doesnt work ?

Comment: Nope, I made sure N is a string and I have attached the link to the screenshot of the tab which opens up
https://prnt.sc/12cxtom